# Horizontal scroll bar - mobile style - media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I am working on a mobile stylesheet for a client and am getting horizontal scrollbars on the iphone. I am using the ios simulator for testing so not sure if that is the reason.

- I have a div #container with a width of 100%. Container contains all content for the page.
- No padding or margins.
- I have tried making it 99, 98, 97 % just to see if it still shows up, and it does...
- I am using overflow-x: hidden

Is there a technique I am forgetting or something I am missing here? I have done a few mobile stylesheets before (on more simple sites) and didn't run into this problem.

Here is a link:

http://www.insomniacdesign.co.php5-24.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/roche/prototype-r4/core-template.php

Comment: Have you tried to use something like `overflow-x: hidden;`?

Comment: I only get horizontal scroll bars on your "non media queried" site, both in browser and on www.testiphone.com

Comment: Strange I am not getting horiz scroll on the non media queried site. It is a pretty rigid style and design...

Answer (score 1):

It might be the resolution of your iphone - If I resize my browser to 320 it looks fine, but I get H' scroll between that and the higher res style.

update: don't know if this helps but looking at it again, your page reverts to the larger style once it gets below 320. Do you see your grey bars on your phone to indicate which sets of styles the media query is applying?

Looking at it on Android your menus that begin 'MyRoche' and 'News and Stories' render wider than then menus beginning 'best Practices' and 'Custom Career Map...' lower down,

The upper two go off left and right on my 320px wide screen - hope this helps.

Comment: Yea the browser works fine but on the iphone simulator I am getting the scroll bar. Just tested on the phone as well and same issue.

Comment: Next thing I'd try is removing all your content from #container temporarily. that will tell you if your CSS on #container is working. Then begin to add elements back in, testing in between, just in case one of your elements has a style that's pushing things out.

Comment: Ah, I see you're testing this now. Try the page without the those upper menus in place (see updated answer)

Comment: yea its something in the header. Thanks. Not sure why I didn't narrow it down before asking this question. How do I mark that comment as helpful..?